# `Error: Cannot connect` while running `detox test` on 2 tests files

Tags: react-native, functional-testing, detox

I've installed Detox on my React Native project and it seemed to run fine until I added a second test file. Apparently, after running first file's tests, it changes the listening port for some reasons and therefore couldn't connect to the *new device*.

Here are my files and terminal logs :

**Terminal log**

```
detox[59310] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:51515...
detox[59310] INFO:  Example is assigned to emulator-11304 (Pixel_API_29_AOSP)
detox[59310] INFO:  Example: should show hello screen after tap
detox[59310] INFO:  Example: should show hello screen after tap [OK]

 PASS  e2e/test.spec.js (14.63 s)
  Example
    ✓ should show hello screen after tap (833 ms)

detox[59310] INFO:  [DetoxServer.js] server listening on localhost:51603...
detox[59310] ERROR: [EmulatorTelnet.js/TELNET_ERROR] 
  err: Cannot connect
detox[59310] ERROR: Error: Cannot connect
detox[59310] INFO:  E is assigned to undefined
detox[59310] INFO:  E: qwe
detox[59310] INFO:  E: qwe [SKIPPED]

detox[59310] ERROR: [EmulatorTelnet.js/TELNET_ERROR] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:23
  err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:23
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
detox[59310] ERROR: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:23
detox[59310] WARN:  at node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:261:15 
 Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
```

**e2e/test.e2e.js** (first test file)

```js
describe('Example', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await device.launchApp();
  });

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should show hello screen after tap', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.text('AVC Diag'))).toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

**e2e/test2.e2e.js** (second test file)

```js
describe('E', () => {
    beforeAll(async () => {
      await device.launchApp();
    });
  
    beforeEach(async () => {
      await device.reloadReactNative();
    });
  
    it('qwe', async () => {
      await expect(element(by.text('AVC Diag'))).toBeVisible();
    });
  });
```

**e2e/config.json**

```json
{
    "testEnvironment": "./environment",
    "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
    "testTimeout": 120000,
    "testRegex": "\\.e2e\\.js$",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this issue? Didn't find any clues using my best friend Google...

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem.